# Replace +200 values from my dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, database

I want to change the value of my data in my dataframe.
Obviously, I can use the replace function.

```py
df['COLUMN'].replace(['SOC','MR','MME',...,'N230'], [0,1,2,...,230], inplace=True)
```

However, since there are more than 200 different values I'm looking for a method to avoid replacing the 200+ values with this method.

Comment: If you know the 200 values in advance, `.replace(values, list(range(len(values)))` should do...

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to replace with just unique random numbers, you can use the sklearn label encoder.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df['Column'])
df['Column']=le.transform(df['Column'])
#if you want to revert the changes
df['Column']=le.inverse_transform(df['Column'])
```

Check the documentation : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html